# Can't see files in a folder in nautilus, but I know they are there

Tags: nautilus, files

I have this directory in my home which contains some files and subdirectories but it shows in nautilus as a blank folder.

But I can see files when:

1. checking properties
2. using `ls -a`
3. searching for any file in the directory

[image]

Comment: Try `git add -A` and check again

Comment: nothing happened.

Comment: Did you run that i the directory in question? Run `git status` and post the output here

Comment: yes i ran it there and the ouput it gives is **On branch release
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean**